# How to add geojson in my leaflet map? the json file can't be seen in map

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I tried to load geojson file into my map. my geojson file is located in another folder called "data" and name of geojson is "street.json". I want to load this data to my leaflet map. how is possible? I tried the following code:

```
L.geoJSON('data/street.json').addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use es6 you can use

`import street from "./data/street.json";` where street is your geojson file

and then use `L.geoJSON(street).addTo(map)`

Here is an [es6 example](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-frost-66mk5) with a geojson to see it live.

**Edit**

Without using es6 what you need to do is:

Having created a folder data and a file street.json you need to store the json inside street.json with a variable for instance

```
var street = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
       {
          "type": "Feature",
          "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
              [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
              [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535]
          ]
       },
       ...
}
```

and then import it on index.html as

```
<script src="./data/street.json"></script>
```

inside `<body>`.
Make sure you create the folder inside the root of your project.

Therefore you would have something like this in your body:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./data/street.json"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

and then reference it with the variable street you defined inside `street.json`:

```
L.geoJSON(street).addTo(map)
```

[plain js demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/WfZpOm1MCwgm92070scG?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But I am not familiar with es6. I have to do it from JavaScript or jquery. Is there any other idea?

Comment: I edited my answer and included also an example without using es6

Comment: Thank you ! I found my mistake. I didn't mention the variable 'street' in my street.json file, so this error was occurred.